# How to get value of ComboBox rather than text

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox `cmbCourses` and I am populating my this code

```
var _courses = new DatabaseHandler().GetAllCourses();
            foreach (var a in _courses)
            {
                ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
                item.Text = a.Value;
                item.Value = a.Key;

                cmbCourses.Items.Add(a.Value);
            }

 public Dictionary<int, String> GetAllCourses()
    {
        Dictionary<int, String> courses = new Dictionary<int, String>();

        var connection = DatabaseConnector.Instance();

        if(connection.IsConnect())
        {
            connection.Connection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM courses";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection.Connection);
            cmd.Prepare();
            var result = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(result.Read())
            {
                courses.Add(result.GetInt16(0), result.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        connection.Connection.Close();

        return courses;
    }
```

But when I try to get key it shows value instead
using this code

```
MessageBox.Show(cmbCourses.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: Is that what you are looking for ``((ComboboxItem)cmbCourses.SelectedItem).Value``? But if I am not mistaken there should also be a ``SelectedValue`` member, so use ``cmbCourses.SelectedValue``

Comment: Strange! `((ComboboxItem)cmbCourses.SelectedItem).Value` this gives me correct answer but `cmbCourses.SelectedValue` still says null object

Comment: Try to set the ``ValueMember`` to ``cmbCourses.ValueMember = "Value";``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only adding the value to the `ComboBox`. Add the `KeyValuePair` to the `ComboBox` and set the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` properties:

```
var _courses = new DatabaseHandler().GetAllCourses();
foreach (var a in _courses)
{
    cmbCourses.Items.Add(a);
}
cmbCourses.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
cmbCourses.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
```

You can then get the key of the selected item like this:

```
var item = cmbCourses.SelectedItem as KeyValuePair<int, String>;
if (item != null)
    MessageBox.Show(item.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GetValue() method to get the value rather than the display text:

```
MessageBox.Show(cmbCourses.GetValue().ToString());
```

Comment: There is not `GetValue()` method

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have problem in adding items to your combobox, you are adding only the value by this line `cmbCourses.Items.Add(a.Value);`, Can you try this :

`cmbCourses.Items.Add(item);`

Then you can use this line to get the value :

```
MessageBox.Show(cmbCourses.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Don't forget to set these for your combobox :

```
cmbCourses.DisplayMember = "YOUR DISPLAY FIELD NAME";
cmbCourses.ValueMember = "YOUR VALUE FIELD NAME";
```

Comment: Nice find, didnt see he is adding `a.Value`.

Comment: God! I did it, but it still says null object!

Comment: Not sure if he is using WPF.

Comment: @RandRandom - You are right, though `ComboboxItem` exists in WPF by default and i assumed that he is using that.

Comment: Yeah, but ComboxItem doesnt have ``Text`` and ``Value`` members, also thought that its an in-build class but that doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: But it sure is "annoying" when someone asks an UI question but doesnt declare what UI he is using.